# apache/mod_rewrite Remove filename from URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite URLs like so:

```
domain.com?file=home => domain.com/home
domain.com/unwanted?file=home => domain.com/home
```

I was able to do the first using this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ?file=$1 [L]
```

but I'm unable to figure out the second part.

Comment: Is "unwanted" actually "index.php" or some other index file? If so, the one line you already have works for both.

Comment: I'm using pluck CMS and it generates the URLs without a domain or filename, like so: ?file=target. After I add the rule above and browse to domain.com/home, the browser interprets the newly generated links on the page as home?file=target and this throws of pluck. I want get rid of the first part before the '?' to make it work.